# Discrepency between lmerTest, mixed and aov results

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am running a mixed effects model to explore the relationship between factors of `Group` (2 levels), `Age` (quantitative), and `Stim.Type` (2 levels) on `FA` as the DV. To validate the p values I got for terms when I ran the model using `lmer` with `lmerTest` I subsequently tried using `afex::mixed` and `aov`, which yielded rather diffrent results (see below for all three outputs). My question is: why I am getting discrepancies between these, especially what seems to be attributing significant effects either to `Group` or `Group:Stim.Type`? Which results can I trust here? Is there a problem with my model specification somewhere, or just slightly different algorithms leading to different outputs?

When I run the model with `lmer` using `lmerTest` as: `lmer(FA ~ Group * Stim.Type + Age.Z * Group + (Stim.Type|Subject),CtxFGNG.FA.Rates.Ctx.eat)`

```
Fixed effects:
                      Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            0.23149    0.02744 51.87000   8.435 2.68e-11 ***
GroupBN                0.03059    0.04028 51.87000   0.760  0.45097    
Stim.TypeFood          0.08308    0.01923 54.00000   4.321 6.71e-05 ***
Age.Z                 -0.07734    0.02733 52.00000  -2.830  0.00661 ** 
GroupBN:Stim.TypeFood  0.06946    0.02822 54.00000   2.462  0.01705 *  
GroupBN:Age.Z          0.08795    0.03812 52.00000   2.307  0.02504 *
```

However when I use `afex::mixed`: `mixed(FA ~ Group * Stim.Type + Age.Z * Group + (Stim.Type|Subject),CtxFGNG.FA.Rates.Ctx.eat)`

I get:

```
           Effect     F ndf   ddf F.scaling p.value
1           Group  2.93   1 52.00      1.00     .09
2       Stim.Type 69.73   1 54.00      1.00  <.0001
3           Age.Z  2.95   1 52.00      1.00     .09
4 Group:Stim.Type  6.06   1 54.00      1.00     .02
5     Group:Age.Z  5.13   1 52.00      1.00     .03
```

And when I run `summary(aov(FA ~ Group * Stim.Type + Age.Z * Group + Error(Stim.Type/Subject),CtxFGNG.FA.Rates.eat))`

The result is:

```
Error: Stim.Type:Subject
                 Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
Group             1  0.330  0.3302   4.851 0.02979 * 
Age.Z             1  0.360  0.3601   5.291 0.02340 * 
Group:Stim.Type   1  0.101  0.1008   1.481 0.22632   
Group:Age.Z       1  0.667  0.6669   9.797 0.00226 **
Residuals       106  7.215  0.0681
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your random statement you specified `+(Stim.Type|Subject)`, which means you are estimating random intercepts for`Subject` and allow for random slopes of `Stim.Type` within `Subject`. In your `aov` statement your specified `Error(Stim.Type/Subject)`, which means `Subject` nested in `Stim.Type`. You could try to change the random effect to `+(Stim.Type/Subject)` and compare this with the `aov` output.

However, since you didn't provide any data, I cannot say which random statement would be best in your case. Feel free to update your question.